# Do subprocesses keep pipes open?

Tags: bash, process, fork, ruby

I am trying to understand the behaviour of programs that launch subprocesses, when run in a pipeline.

This bash program, fork.sh, prints and returns immediately:

```bsh
(sleep 1) &
echo 'here'
```

But when connected to a pipe, the read end seems to wait for the sleep to  complete.

```bsh
$ time bash fork.sh | wc
       1       1       5

real    0m1.014s
```

I've also tried this in Ruby, with some extra calls to try to prevent the sleep from blocking:

```
Process.detach(fork { sleep 1 })
puts 'here'
```

```
fork {
  sleep 1
  Process.daemon
}
puts 'here'
```

But they behave the same.

I would like to know what causes this (in terms of Unix, file descriptors, etc), and if there's a way to re-write any of these so that the pipeline  returns in under a second.

---

edit: the answer below helped me notice the problem with the Ruby example: the `daemon()` call must come first. I had thought it was somehow applied to the entire process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. child processes inherit all the file descriptors from their parents.
2. When executing a command (like your `sleep` here assuming your shell doesn't have it builtin), only the file descriptors marked with the *close-on-exec* flag are closed, but shells never set that flag on stdout (fd 1).
3. a pipe *reader* will only get an EOF when **all** the file descriptors pointing to its writing end have been closed.

> ```
> time bash fork.sh | wc
> ```

You should have your `sleep` process (as started from `fork.sh`) give up on its stdout, which points to the write end of the pipe `wc` is reading from; in `fork.sh`:

```
(sleep 1 >/dev/null) &
echo 'here'
```

In this case `sleep .. >&-` (which closes the stdout, without redirecting it elsewhere) could work too, but I don't recommend this in general, because if the process opens some file afterwards, the returned file descriptor will be 1 = stdout, which may break assumptions and trigger bugs.